# ERROR :ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

```
create table ward
(
wnum int primary key,
wname varchar(30),
phoneno int,
wloc varchar(50),
chnursename varchar(20) constraint ward_fk references charge_nurse
);
```

```
create table charge_nurse
(
chnurse varchar(20) constraint charge_nurse_pk primary key,
stnum int constraint charge_nurse_fk references staff
);
```

```
create table staff
(
stname varchar(20),
stnum int constraint staff_pk primary key,
addr varchar(20),
phoneno int,
stposition varchar(30),
specality varchar(30) unique,
shift varchar(10),
noofhoursperweek int
);
```

```
create table generalsupplies
(
itnum int constraint generalsupplies_pk primary key,
itname varchar(20) unique,
quantityinstock int,
reorder varchar(10),
despt varchar(10),
costperunit int
);
```

```
create table pharmasupplies
(
dnum int constraint pharmasupplies_pk primary key,
dname varchar(30) unique,
despt varchar(20),
dosage_Mg int,
quantityinstock int,
reorder varchar(10),
costperunit int
);
```

While creating the below table I am facing problem:

> ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint

```
create table centralsupplies
(
wardnum int constraint centralsupplies_fk references ward,
itemnum int constraint centralsupplies_fk references generalsupplies,
drugnum int constraint centralsupplies_fk references pharmasupplies,
quantity_required varchar(20),
staffname varchar(10) references staff(stname),
staffnum int constraint centralsupplies_fk references staff,
regnum int unique,
dateord date,
daterec date
);
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please format your post with code tags ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create table statement has **four** foreign keys all called `centralsupplies_fk`. That is not allowed: constraint names must be unique within a schema. You must give each one a different name.

It is usual practice to include the referenced table in the key name. So

```
create table centralsupplies
(
wardnum int constraint centralsupplies_ward_fk references ward,
itemnum int constraint centralsupplies_generalsupplies_fk references generalsupplies,
drugnum int constraint centralsupplies_pharmasupplies_fk references pharmasupplies,
quantity_required varchar(20),
staffname varchar(10) references staff(stname),
staffnum int constraint centralsupplies_staff_fk references staff,
regnum int unique,
dateord date,
daterec date
)
```

Also you have another foreign key constraint on STAFFNAME which you have not named. You do not need to name constraints, the system will generate a unique one for you, but it's generally a good idea to name them, not least because it is easier to diagnose relational integrity error messages with meaningfully named constraints.

However, in this case the correct solution is to **drop the STAFFNAME column**. You already have a foreign on the STAFF table, and you should join to that table whenever you need to display a value for STAFFNAME. Besides you do not have a unique constraint on `staff.stname` column, so the foreign key statement will fail: foreign keys can only reference primary or unique keys.

Answer (score 1):

You use 3 times the same constraint name `centralsupplies_fk` in your centralsupplies table.

3 constraints = 3 constraint names